# Problems with the lme function with nested variables: (any(notIntX <- !apply(X, 2, const))

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I'm trying to fit a mixed-effects model in which I have covariates that are nested (VarX5 | VarX6) and are considered fixed effects.

However, I am trying to adjust the data and the following message appears:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

dados$VarCat=as.factor(dados$VarCat)
dados$VarX5=as.factor(dados$VarX5)
dados$VarX6=as.factor(dados$VarX6)

model <- lme(log(Resp)~log(VarX1)+log(VarX2)+(VarX3)+(VarX4)+VarX5|VarX6 ,random = ~1|VarCat, 
                 dados, method="REML")

Error in if (any(notIntX <- !apply(X, 2, const))) { : 
  valor ausente onde TRUE/FALSE necessário
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying the categorical variables properly. In `nlme:lme` they go in the `random` option (the error is for trying to pass factors direct into the formula). In `lme4: lmer` they are enclosed in parentheses inside the formula.

```
model <- nlme::lme(
  log(Resp) ~ log(VarX1) + log(VarX2) + VarX3 + VarX4,
  random = ~ VarCat | VarX5:VarX6,
  data = dados)

model <- lme4::lmer(
  log(Resp) ~ log(VarX1) + log(VarX2) + VarX3 + VarX4 + (VarCat | VarX5:VarX6),
  data = dados)
```

I don't know what you want with the model, so maybe the `:` operator is not the most appropriate. Check the details for the `formula` parameter in the `lmer` help page.

Comment: Thank you @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta!